# Creating entities in jhipster without changing any other entities

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

I have a Jhiptser project and I created the entities using jdl file. now I want to add one more table. I created the following jdl file.

```
enum DistributionType {
  Prize(Prize),
  Donation (Donation)
}
entity PrizeDistribution {
  name String required
  createdDate LocalDate required
  details String required
  image String
  type DistributionType required
  activeFrom LocalDate required
  activeTo LocalDate
}

service PrizeDistribution with serviceClass
dto PrizeDistribution with mapstruct
paginate PrizeDistribution with pagination
```

but when I am trying to import this, all other entity files are chowing as changed and I need to manually enter "n" to prevent it from changing. is there any simpler way to import one and only entity that I need?

the following is the log i am getting in the cmd after running jhipster import-jdl entity.jdl

```
INFO! Switching to JHipster installed locally in current project's node repository (node_modules)
INFO! Using bundled JHipster

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝
                            https://www.jhipster.tech
Welcome to JHipster v7.9.3
INFO! Executing import-jdl .\entity.jdl
INFO! The JDL is being parsed.
info: The dto option is set for PrizeDistribution, the 'serviceClass' value for the 'service' is gonna be set for this entity if no other value has been set.
INFO! Found entities: PrizeDistribution.
INFO! The JDL has been successfully parsed
INFO! Generating 0 applications.
INFO! Generating 1 entity.
INFO! Generating entities for application undefined in a new parallel process

Found the .jhipster\NewsLetter.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\NewsLetterSubscriber.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\Customer.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\Address.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\CustomerAddress.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\Image.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\Campaign.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\Product.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\ProductItem.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\ProductCategory.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\ProductVariation.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\ProductVariationOption.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\ProductConfiguration.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\Promotion.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\PromotionCategory.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\Prize.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\Lottery.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\ProductLottery.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\ShopOrder.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\ShippingMethod.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\OrderItem.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\UserReview.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\Payment.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\OtpRegister.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


Found the .jhipster\PrizeDistribution.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!

     info Creating changelog for entities NewsLetter,NewsLetterSubscriber,Customer,Address,CustomerAddress,Image,Campaign,Product,ProductItem,ProductCategory,ProductVariation,ProductVariationOption,ProductConfiguration,Promotion,PromotionCategory,Prize,Lottery,ProductLottery,ShopOrder,ShippingMethod,OrderItem,UserReview,Payment,OtpRegister,PrizeDistribution
```

**NOTE**

I deleted all the contents from the .jhipster folder and then ran the command. at that time, only the required entity changes were created. Is it the correct approach? or is there any simpler approach?